# How to populate a row of buttons with folders?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm very new to making visual programs and pretty new to C# to begin with.

I'm attempting to make a file browser that opens up files as well; I have several other questions but I'll just start with one.

I'm trying to populate a list of tabs/buttons across the top of the program with folders under a directory, and then when you click on one of the tabs it will change the tree view to show that directory (and sub-directories/files.)

I've got the file browser working- still working on opening files but I believe I got most of that done. I just need to figure out how to make these tabs.

EDIT: This is a windows application being created though VS Express.

Comment: WinForms or WPF or browser-based or ...?

Comment: Sorry- this is a Windows Application created via VS Express.

Comment: OK, but "Windows application" can still be WinForms or WPF (Windows Presentation Fundation), and the answer to your question will probably depend on that information. And you are supposed to indicate the technology as a "tag" on your question.